# Is there a way to verify that given targets are marked .PHONY in makefile?

Tags: gnu-make

I am having a bunch of make files in different projects that I want to verify against some criteria of all targets or a list of targets are marked .PHONY.

I am not sure whether such a test already exists or if it is possible to introduce one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no.

`make` / `gmake` itself has no functionality to print that.

However, it's easy to find out yourself from `make`'s dependency/target database output:

```
make -nsp --no-print-directory --always-make
      |||   |                     |
      |||   |                     run, no matter whether
      |||   |                     parts have already been built
      |||   |                     
      |||   don't print the directory structure
      |||
      ||\--- print the database
      |\---- be silent, otherwise
      \----- don't actually build anything
```

prints what `make` figured out are all targets.

```
make -nsp --no-print-directory --always-make | grep -E '^\.PHONY:'
```

prints all the targets that are dependencies of the `.PHONY` "pseudo"-target.

You can then do with that list whatever you want :)